# Getting uninitialized memory warning at compilation

Tags: c++

I made code that has one option where user input some numbers and other option that multiply two of the numbers from user all made in 2 cases, but I got error. I'm totally new to programming just to clear.

```
struct proizvod
{
    char materijal;
    int k;  // kolicina
    int c; // cijena
};

int main()
{

    int izbor;
    cout << endl
        << " 1 - Unos podataka.\n"
        << " 2 - Rezultat.\n"
        << " 3 - Izlaz.\n"
        << " Unesi broj i pritisni enter: ";
    cin >> izbor;
    switch(izbor)
    {
        proizvod p;
        case 1:
            cout << "\nUnesite ime proizvoda: ";
            cin.get(p.materijal);
            cout << "\nUnesite kolicinu proizvoda: ";
            cin >> p.k;
            cout << "\nUnesite cijenu proizvoda: ";
            cin >> p.c;
            break;
        case 2:
            int r;
            r = p.k * p.c; // multiply

        while (izbor!= 3);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

## edit

> Error     C2086    'int r': redefinition  ConsoleApplication1

Comment: It's a warning not an error. `r = p.k * p.c;` if you choose case  2 then you multiply uninitialized variables.

Comment: You should learn programming basics: flow, loops etc. It's not a single issue in your code that could be fixed, the whole flow is incorrect.

Comment: if the user enter 2 then you do the "case 2" and you do `p.k * p.c` but _p_ is not initialized so the behavior is undefined. Also `while (izbor!= 3);` will loop forrever because _izbor_ values 2 and cannot become 3

Comment: @oblivion you do `while (izbor!= 3)` without having initialized _izbor_ before, the behavior is undefined, and you do not fixed the initial problem

Comment: Thank you so much ! I appreciate it !! @oblivion

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/gxIhb9

Comment: @bruno too many uninitialized variables :) I just corrected while and one } that was missing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several problems in your code :

- if the user enter 1 you read a *char* but you will get the return you enter after the character 1 to finish the input for `cin >> izbor;` (or any character enter after the 1)
- if the user enter 2 you do `p.k * p.c` using non initialized values, the behavior is undefined
- still in case the user enter 2  you do the loop `while (izbor!= 3);` which never end because *izbor* values 2 and cannot change to the value 3.
- Note also *r* is set but never used.

If I understand your hope you want something like that, still using just a *char* for *proizvod* even probably you want a *string* :

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct proizvod
{
    char materijal;
    int k;  // kolicina
    int c; // cijena
};

int main()
{
  proizvod p;
  bool pSet = false;

  for (;;) {
    cout << endl
         << " 1 - Unos podataka.\n"
         << " 2 - Rezultat.\n"
         << " 3 - Izlaz.\n"
         << " Unesi broj i pritisni enter: ";

    int izbor;

    if (!(cin >> izbor)) {
      cerr << "the choice is not an integer, abort" << endl;
      return -1;
    }

    switch (izbor) {
    case 1:
      cout << "\nUnesite ime proizvoda: ";
      if (!(cin >> p.materijal)) {
        cerr << "premature EOF" << endl;
        return -1;
      }
      cout << "\nUnesite kolicinu proizvoda: ";
      if (!(cin >> p.k)) {
        cerr << "quantity is not an integer, abort" << endl;
        return -1;
      }
      cout << "\nUnesite cijenu proizvoda: ";
      if (!(cin >> p.c)) {
        cerr << "price not an integer, abort" << endl;
        return -1;
      }
      pSet = true;
      break;
    case 2:
      if (!pSet)
        cerr << "you did not enter the price and quantity" << endl;
      else
        cout << "Rezultat : " << p.k * p.c << endl;
      break;
    case 3:
      return 0;
    default:
      cerr << "invalid choice" << endl;
    }
  }

  return 0; // cannot be reach
}
```

I preferred to use English for the new sentences to not take risk

Compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ g++ -g -pedantic -Wextra -Wall c.cc
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out

 1 - Unos podataka.
 2 - Rezultat.
 3 - Izlaz.
 Unesi broj i pritisni enter: aze
the choice is not an integer, abort
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out

 1 - Unos podataka.
 2 - Rezultat.
 3 - Izlaz.
 Unesi broj i pritisni enter: 4
invalid choice

 1 - Unos podataka.
 2 - Rezultat.
 3 - Izlaz.
 Unesi broj i pritisni enter: 2
you did not enter the price and quantity

 1 - Unos podataka.
 2 - Rezultat.
 3 - Izlaz.
 Unesi broj i pritisni enter: 1

Unesite ime proizvoda: a

Unesite kolicinu proizvoda: 2

Unesite cijenu proizvoda: 33

 1 - Unos podataka.
 2 - Rezultat.
 3 - Izlaz.
 Unesi broj i pritisni enter: 2
Rezultat : 66

 1 - Unos podataka.
 2 - Rezultat.
 3 - Izlaz.
 Unesi broj i pritisni enter: 3
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

As you can see I also check the `cin >>` success, in case of an error I just abort the execution but it is also possible to flush the invalid input to redo.